# How can I get more results when using the license parameter on soundcloud API?

Tags: api, licensing, limit, soundcloud

Does anyone know a way of getting more tracks when using the license parameter. It seems to be limited to 250 when this is in place. When I don't use the license parameter however, I can return up to 8000.

With the License (250 returned)

https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks.json?client_id=76c1334ef21c70d72dc89661e638258f&limit=1&offset=249&license=cc-by-sa

without the license: (up to 8000)
https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks.json?client_id=76c1334ef21c70d72dc89661e638258f&limit=1&offset=7500&q=sound

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your question.

We are currently working on this and estimated time of arrival for offset on license sorting is the end of this month.